# Swift moveBy Method Won't Take in CGFloat Parameter

Tags: swift

```
if gameStarted == false {
    let spawn = SKAction.run({
        () in

        self.createPlatforms()

    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.5)
    let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
    let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
    self.run(spawnDelayForever)

    let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + platformPair.frame.width)
    let movePlatforms = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval(0.01 * Double(distance))
    let removePlatforms = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePlatforms, removePlatforms])

    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 150))

} else {
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 150))
}
```

I keep getting this error for my `x` value in my `let movePlatforms` `moveBy` function:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'CGVector'

Distance is a `CGFloat` and the `x` parameter in the `moveBy` method is a `CGFloat`. Not sure why it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on this line:

```
let movePlatforms = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval(0.01 * Double(distance)))
```